# Arrow function in JS

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Please advise how to turn next function to arrow function in JS. The code is used to check email validation.

```js
function checkGmail() {
  let emailvalidation = document.getElementById('email').value;
  if (emailvalidation.length < 12) {
    document.getElementById('site-heading').style.color = "red";
  } else if (emailvalidation.indexOf('@gmail.com') == -1) {
    document.getElementById('site-heading').style.color = "red";
  } else if (emailvalidation.indexOf('.') < emailvalidation.length - 4) {

    document.getElementById('site-heading').style.color = "red";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('site-heading').style.color = "green";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to turn it into an arrow function? Have you read up on arrow function syntax? Tried to do anything? What happened?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and your attempts to convert it - there is very little to convert anyway

Answer (score 0):

turning it into an arrow function is simple just change this:

```
function checkGmail() {
   // your code logic in here
}
```

to

```
const checkGmail = () => {
   // your code logic in here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The first line const checkGmail = () => {  is exactly what I did. But it doesn't work.  Can you please advise the full code? I mean how I can change the full function from regular function to arrow function?

Comment: can you explain "what didn't work" so I can understand more

Comment: "doesn't work" is not useful. Please post your HTML and how you call the function

Comment: yes copy all the inner function code inside `const checkGmail = () => { //code goes here}`. let me know if that works

Comment: I am learning in web developer course. The task was to create input with emeail adress and to check the validation with arrow function. When I did the task with regular function. The validation checking work. But when I tried to do it with arrow function - it doesn't work.

Comment: " yes copy all the inner function code inside const checkGmail = () => { //code goes here}. let me know if that work"   That exactly what I did. It doesn't work. It only works with regular function.

Comment: Thank to everyone. The problem was with browser when I tried it in explorer it didn't work. I tried it in Chrome - it works :))

Comment: yeh it looks like they aren't supported: https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Answer (score 0):

How about simplification and DRY?

Complete code - it seems slightly larger than yours because I have all event handlers you need (except the submit handler)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.getElementById("email").addEventListener("input", e => {
    const heading = document.getElementById('site-heading');
    let emailvalidation = e.target.value; // or this.value if using function above
    let valid = emailvalidation.length >= 12 &&
      emailvalidation.indexOf('@gmail.com') !== -1 &&
      emailvalidation.indexOf('.') >= emailvalidation.length - 4;
    heading.classList.remove("green", "red")
    heading.classList.add(valid ? "green" : "red")
  })
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}

.green {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<h3 id="site-heading">Please fill you gmail address</h3>
<input type="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Enter an email" />
```